# Updating mongodb document with new document id

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am trying to `$push` a document id to a collection but it seems to not working. I don't understand what I am doing wrong here. Please help me out.
this is how user model looks like in my codebase

```
 const userSchema = new Schema({
    first_name: String,
    ...
    products: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Product' }]
});

const UserModel = model('User', userSchema);
```

product model

```
const productSchema = new Schema({
    name: string,
    ...
    user_id : [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }]
});

const ProductModel = model('Product', productSchema);
```

controller

```
const savedUser = await new UserModel({ ...user }).save();
product.user_id = savedUser._id;
const savedProduct = await new ProductModel(product).save();
savedUser.update({ $push: { products: savedProduct._id } });
console.log(savedUser.populated('products')); // undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/document.html#document_Document-populated):

> If the path was not populated, returns undefined.

You need to `populate` before `populated` can be used.